# Rails 5: partial value refresh only after second update in a row (AJAX)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have */views/layouts/_navigation.html.erb* where inside there is user profile info rendered:

```
<a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">
  <span class="clear">
    <span class="block m-t-xs">
      <div id="userprofile">
        <%= render 'users/userprofile' %>
      </div>
    </span>
  </span>
</a>
```

In */views/users/_userprofile.html.erb* I have this:

`<strong class="font-bold"><%= current_user.name %></strong><b class="caret"></b>`

There is working Update action (modal window with AJAX) for Users controller where user info can be updated in table. In particular */views/users/update.js.erb* I have added line which should change user profile info as well:

```
$('#dialog').modal('toggle');
$('#user_<%= @user.id %>').replaceWith('<%= j render (@user) %>')

$('#userprofile').html("<%= j render(partial: 'users/userprofile') %>");
```

At the moment `_userprofile.html.erb` **partial is rendering in console and there is no error thrown, but the value is refreshed in view only after second Update action in a row** In addition it shows 1st value, not second which is updated:

1. start state: partial value "AAA"
2. 1st attempt: input "BBB", partial renders value "AAA"
3. 2nd attempt: input "CCC", partial renders value "BBB"

I'm a bit confused as I have no idea what is the reason for this behaviour - why partial value is not refreshed on first Update action? I'll be happy for any hint here. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

After every update, try reloading the values by doing `current_user.reload` in the controller.
This might solve the issue. Also if you can post the controller code as well it would be helpful incase the above didn't solve the issue.